# How do I pass an empty string with double quotes to a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that will accept as additional arguments on the command line an empty string with double quotes. I want the script to pass those arguments along with the double quoted empty string if that is provided, but instead the command interpreter seems to interpret such an argument as an empty string and strips away the quotes. Is there any way to do this?

As a simple example I would have in the file script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/myapp $1 $2
```

If I run at the prompt:

```
$ ./script.sh arg1 ""
```

The script just executes `"/home/myapp arg1"`, but misses/ignores the second argument `("")`. I want it to preserve this empty string and instead execute: `/home/myapp arg1 ""`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect how many positional parameters were passed to your script by [examining the `$#` parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters).  For example, if this is 2 or greater, then you know that something was passed for `$2`, even if `$2` is empty (quotes removed by calling shell).  The following implements that logic, and passes `""` to the called program (in this case `echo`) if the parameter was passed but empty:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then
    if [ "$2" ]; then
        arg2="$2"
    else
        arg2='""'
    fi
    echo "$1 $arg2"
elif [ $# == 1 ]; then
    echo "$1"
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./args.sh a
a
$ ./args.sh a ""
a ""
$ ./args.sh a 1
a 1
$
```

Comment: Setting `arg2='""'` will look fine when you echo it, but if you try to use it to pass a blank string to something else (as in `/home/myapp $1 $arg2`), it won't work -- it'll pass the string consisting of two double-quotes, not an empty string.

Comment: @GordonDavisson *I want it to preserve this empty string and instead execute: `/home/myapp arg1 ""`*  Isn't this precisely what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, you are correct this is what I was looking for. The called program actually expects to see the "" including the double quotes and doesn't work properly if nothing or an empty string without the quotes is passed. This is why I selected your answer. For anyone interested, myapp is really the bitcoin client, it has a certain command bitcoind getaddressesbyaccount <account>. The default account is always "" so for this command to work properly the quotes have to be there. I run the client as a non-privileged user and my script uses sudo to run this command with the -u flag.

Answer (score 15):

You are correctly passing an empty string argument to the script.

It is the script that is messing it up:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/myapp $1 $2
```

The script is not protecting the expansion of `$1` and `$2` from word-splitting. This means that if `$1` and `$2` contain multiple words, those turn into individual arguments, and if either of them expand to nothing, they simply disappear.

This should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/myapp "$1" "$2"
```

In general, you can make your script pass all of its arguments to the invoked program, like this:

```
/home/myapp "$@"
```

The quotes are just shell syntax; they are not part of the argument data itself. When you type `program ""` into the shell, at the operating system level, the program receives an empty C language string: a pointer to a null byte. There are no quotes.

You can pass the argument `""` (a two-character string made of two double quotes) but that is not an empty argument. A way to do that is, for instance, `'""'`: wrap it in single quotes.

The only reason to do things like that is when you're manipulating shell syntax at a meta-level: passing around pieces of shell script *source code*, such as quoted tokens, empty or otherwise.  The shell has a command called `eval` which takes source code as an argument (or multiple arguments) and evaluates it.

```
empty_shell_string_syntax='""'    # this variable holds the characters ""

eval empty_var=$empty_shell_string_syntax   # empty_var gets set to empty string
```

before `eval` is invoked, the command line is subject to expansion. That expansion removes the syntax `$empty_shell_string_sytnax` and replaces it with the contents, the characters `""`.  So then eval gets the string `empty_var=""`. It evaluates this, and so `empty_var` is set to the empty string, as the syntax indicates.

Comment: You're right about the need to double-quote argument references, but if you unconditionally quote `$2` (`"$2"`), it will _always_ get passed through as an (empty) argument, even when NO 2nd argument was passed in, which is not what the OP intended; `"$@"`, by contrast, works as intended; +1 for the rest of the explanation.

Comment: You can work around the problem @mklement0 mentions by using e.g. `/home/myapp ${1+"$1"} ${2+"$2"}`. This is a bit circuitous, but way it works is the `${var+something}` construct expands to `something` IF `$var` is defined -- thus if `$2` is undefined, `${2+"$2"}` expands to nothing and vanishes; if `$2` is defined (even if it's defined as the empty string), it expands to `"$2"` and the double-quotes protect it from word splitting and vanishing-if-blank.

Answer (score 4):

You can also put them inside a single quote to have their literal values, e.g. :

```
  ]$ echo '""'
  ""
```

For example, in a script:

```
   ]# cat a.bash
     #!/bin/bash        
     echo a$1b

  ]$ ./a.sh '""'
  a""b

  ]$ ./a.sh ""
  ab
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Kaz's helpful explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23306094/45375):
If you **pass `"$@"` through, *empty* arguments will be passed through, too**:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/myapp "$@"
```

Passing through `"$@"` preserves the original arguments *exactly* as passed in - even arguments passed as *empty strings* (passed as, e.g., `''` or `""` or `"$someVar"`, where variable `someVar` is unset or contains an empty string).

---

In case there can be **more than 2 arguments**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copy the (up to) first 2 arguments - whether they're empty strings or not -
# to a separate array.
firstTwo=("${@:1:2}") 
shift; shift  # Remove the first 2 arguments from the arguments array.

# Invoke the app with the (up to) first 2 arguments stored in the new array.
/home/myapp "${firstTwo[@]}"

# Process the remaining arguments, if any.
for a; do
  echo "remaining: [$a]"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You shall escape it using backslash

```
$ ./script.sh arg1 \"\"
```

Can be tested e.g. on echo:

```
$ echo \"\"
""
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree this works, is there any way to not require the user to escape the quotes using some script magic to detect that they entered such an empty string and replace the command with the double quotes?

Comment: @Josh not aware of any such magic. This parsing is done by shell, so you would have to modify the shell to apply different parsing rules.

Answer (score 2):

Escape them with backslashes or put them in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmd=yourcomand;
n=0; for a in "$@"; do n=$((n +1)); cmd="$cmd \${$n+\"\$$n\"}"; done
eval $cmd
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is based on Kaz and Gordon Davisson note above, thank you. Note however that in general the expansion of ${X+"$X"} can yield undesired results depending on what characters the valiable value contains. So it is best to use a general replacement of all variables on command line, only after verifying there is an empty string present. From the above responses I do not see a general solution yet.